# Login to Dropbox with vbscript

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I found a script on here to login to a forum that someone made and I edited it to login to Dropbox, but it still isn't working for me. I am looking for the script to uncheck the "remember me" checkbox and login to Dropbox from a vbs file that I execute on brand new machines.
Here is what I have so far:

```
Call Main

Function Main
    Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "dropbox.com/login"
    Wait IE
    With IE.Document
        .getElementByID("login_email").value = "mypassword"
        .getElementByID("login_password").value = "myemail" 
        .getElementByID("remember_me").checked = "unchecked"
        .getElementsByName("frmLogin")(0).Submit
    End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
```

I changed the ID's that it "gets" in order to set the username and password, but the "frmLogin" I am unsure of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the below example having nodes accessibility extended checks and using `.click` method instead of `.submit`, since the last one leads to 403 error page for me:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim objIE, strMsg

DropBoxLogin objIE, strMsg
MsgBox strMsg

Sub DropBoxLogin(objIE, strMsg)
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.Navigate "https://www.dropbox.com/login"
    Wait objIE
    If Not IsNull(objIE.Document.getElementById("header-account-menu")) Then
        strMsg = "Already logged in"
    Else
        WaitElementById objIE, "regular-login-forms"
        With objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("login-form")(0)
            .item("login_email").value = "mymail@mydomain.com"
            .item("login_password").value = "mypassword"
            .item("remember_me").checked = False
            .getElementsByTagName("button")(0).click
        End With
        WaitElementById objIE, "header-account-menu"
        Wait objIE
        strMsg = "Log in completed"
    End If
End Sub

Sub Wait(objIE)
    Do While objIE.ReadyState < 4 Or objIE.Busy
        WScript.Sleep 10
    Loop
    Do Until objIE.Document.readyState = "complete"
        WScript.Sleep 10
    Loop
End Sub

Sub WaitElementById(objIE, strId)
    Do While IsNull(objIE.Document.getElementById(strId))
        WScript.Sleep 10
    Loop
End Sub
```